# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Account for previous day in Lag / CTE - Use Values from Previous or Next Rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I am following this person's tutorial "[How to Use Values from Previous or Next Rows in a SQL Server Query](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/how-to-use-values-from-previous-or-next-rows-in-a-query-in-sql-server/)".

Here is the main query he is using:

```
;WITH UserActivityWRowNum(RowNumber, User, Activity, ActivityTime, ActivityDate)
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY user, ActivityTime) RowNumber
,User
,Activity
,ActivityTime
,CAST(ActivityTime as DATE) as ActivityDate
FROM dbo.UserActivity

SELECT  LogOns.User, LogOns.ActivityDate
,LogOffs.ActivityTime LogOff
,LogOns.ActivityTime LogOn
, DATEDIFF(minute, LogOffs.ActivityTime, LogOns.ActivityTime) IdleTime
FROM (SELECT * FROM UserActivityWRowNum WHERE Activity='LogOn') LogOns
JOIN (SELECT * FROM UserActivityWRowNum WHERE Activity='LogOff') LogOffs
      ON LogOffs.RowNumber=LogOns.RowNumber - 1
      AND LogOffs.User - LogOns.User
      AND LogOffs.ActivityDate - LogOns.ActivityDate
```

I am trying to account for days when a user would have a logon/logoff cycle between two days. This makes it hard to calculate the total idle time per day. **Essentially, how do I account for a logoff/logon cycle that spans two days and give a total idle time for a specific day? Total idle time per day per user is the expected output as stated in the link**

For example, the below image  shows a logoff activity at row 6. So technically the user was idle for the remaining 7 hours of that day (2013-01-01). 2013-01-02 would have a dummy logoff as the first entry that shows as 2013-01-02 00:00:00

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your question is not clear. What are you expecting as output? To help clarify here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ And images of data are really not very helpful. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: I'd probably do the opposite - figure out how many minutes they worked each day from matching logon-off pairs. If somebody logs on one day and logs off the next, split it into two (or more) days. Then I'd match a date table with the results of that data and and calc it as (24 * 60) - time on as idle time for each date. (If you don't know what a date table is, search for tally table, number table or date table, they're really useful).

Comment: I have added the detail requested.

Also, the first link shows the code used but is in image format. I felt it better to link to the original source so people can see it in original context. I have typed it up and put it into the original question.

Second, the image in my post is used for clarification purposes and does aid in asking the question in my opinion. It does not contain code and is used solely for reference.